# Image is not visible

Tags: graphics

Can someone please explain to me why the picture I inserted is not visible?

```
\documentclass[12 pt,letterpaper,draft]{article}%inicia preambulos
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}% Aqui empieza el documento
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{polli}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have some sort of option like `draft` enabled somewhere? Can you post the code that is responsible in a complete, but minimal `.tex` file?

Comment: Remove the `draft` option

Comment: where do I do it?

Comment: Find the `\documentclass` instruction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments